# Finding a matrix with shared eigen vectors with a given matrix

Tags: matrix-theory, eigenvector

If I have a known matrix A, is there a method to find a matrix B that share all the eigen vectors of Matrix A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any analytic function of $A$ (including such diverse ones as $p(A),$ where $p$ is a polynomial, and $\exp(A)$) will work.

Comment: Moreover, if $A$ has all distinct eigenvalues then all solutions will be of that form.